# Exclude blank column while Joining two SQL server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have set of vehicle parts stored in two tables as per below:

Source Table1:

| Vehicle_ID | Part1 | Part2 | Part3 | Part4 | Part5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |  |  |
| 2 | 10 | 20 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 10 |  |  |  |  |

Source Table2:

| Vehicle_ID | Part6 | Part7 | Part8 | Part9 | Part10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 30 | 50 | 60 |  |  |
| 3 | 30 |  |  |  |  |

Required Table like below:

| Vehicle_ID | Part1 | Part2 | Part3 | Part4 | Part5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |  |
| 2 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 10 | 30 |  |  |  |

Maximum of the ***Part*** column up to 5 only.

I tried ***Union all*** statement but that statement is not relevant for excluding blank columns.

Please share your experience to solve my problem .

Comment: What is the expected output if there are more than 5 parts for a vehicle?

Comment: This appears somewhat of a design flaw - why are parts columns and not rows? If they were rows each could have a rank and be stored in a single table, querying for the top 5 would be easy.

Comment: Expect output only 5 Parts not more than that.

Comment: *"Please share your experience to solve my problem ."* My experiences are fix the design; then you have a much easier time doing the query(s) you want to do.

Comment: Just adding on top of others. you need a better design. it would be a good idea to follow at least the first 3 normalization rules of relational databases. if you keep the current schema your database will have redundant data...

Comment: What is the logic for your desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpivot and pivot the rows in both tables.

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Table1
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 10, 20,   30,   NULL, NULL), 
   (2, 10, 20,   NULL, NULL, NULL), 
   (3, 10, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),     
   (4, 40, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)      
) v (Vehicle_ID, Part1, Part2, Part3, Part4, Part5)

SELECT *
INTO Table2
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 40, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),     
   (2, 30, 50,   60,   NULL, NULL),
   (3, 30, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
   (5, 50, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
) v (Vehicle_ID, Part6, Part7, Part8, Part9, Part10)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Vehicle_ID,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Part END) AS Part1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Part END) AS Part2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Part END) AS Part3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN Part END) AS Part4,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN Part END) AS Part5
FROM (
   SELECT 
      COALESCE(t1.Vehicle_ID, t2.Vehicle_ID) AS Vehicle_ID,
      a.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(t1.Vehicle_ID, t2.Vehicle_ID) ORDER BY a.Part_ID) AS RN
   FROM Table1 t1
   FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Vehicle_ID = t2.Vehicle_ID
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (1, t1.Part1),
      (2, t1.Part2),
      (3, t1.Part3),
      (4, t1.Part4),
      (5, t1.Part5),
      (6, t2.Part6),
      (7, t2.Part7),
      (8, t2.Part8),
      (9, t2.Part9),
      (10, t2.Part10)
   ) a (Part_ID, Part)
   WHERE a.Part IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY Vehicle_ID
```

Result:

| Vehicle_ID | Part1 | Part2 | Part3 | Part4 | Part5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |  |
| 2 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 10 | 30 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 40 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 50 |  |  |  |  |